# How to update data from datatable to sql table?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datatable

I have an sql table with

```
ID(unique) Name status
1          A    0
2          B    0
```

In my code, I retrieve all data into a data table and do some coding.
Based on the results, I will change the results from 0 to 1 or 2

After that, I need to update them back to sql.

My idea is to create a temp table, insert every row into that .. and then update them to the real sql table, delete the temp table.

Not very good, I know. That's why I am asking, is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the content of the table back working with a [CommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx) .

Take a look at this [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommandbuilder) .

Comment: I've heard of that, but I am not sure how to use it in my situation since mine is "update TBLSOMETHING set status= newstatus where id= idfromdatatable". can i add that query in sqldataadapter and put parameters for those 2 variables?

Comment: You have to load the table from database with a datadapter filling a datatable, then change the record you want to change directly in the datatable and so update the target table using command builder, take a look at the example that i've  linked.

Comment: Oh, that's how it works.. i was thinkin the wrong way.. one more question, .Update() will only replace the updated values and not replacing the whole table, rite? coz as I mentioned in my question, my ID is auto increment unique number. btw, Tkz a lot..

Comment: Generally you should add code samples to your answer in the (all too common) event that links go down.